# Alternative way to populate selected value in HTML.Dropdownlistfor in MVC3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In the below code, though model.Title is holding the proper selected value, Its not getting set in the ddl, having id 'Title'.

Can I set the selected value in any other way? (like in document ready?)

```
    <td> 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, Model.TitleList, !Model.IsTitleEditable ? (object)new { id = "Title", @disabled = "disabled", @style = "width:250px;" } : (object)new { id = "Title", @style = "width:250px" })
</td>
```

In my controller the selectlist is getting filled as below:

```
model.TitleList = new SelectList(GetAllTitles(), "Code","Value");
```

In this case as I m using the other overloaded method, how to set the selectedValue property of this selectList?

Comment: Can you show the code that sets model.TitleList and the code that sets model.Title?

Answer (score 3):

**If** you create model.TitleList as an IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, where you set both Text an Value of the SelectListItems **and** the model.Value is one of the Values of the SelectListItems **then** everything should work. So:

```
model.TitleList = GetAllTitles()
            .ToList()
            .Select(i => new SelectListItem { 
                                Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                                Text = i.Description });

model.Title = 5;
```

and in your View:

```
<td> 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, 
                      Model.TitleList, 
                      !Model.IsTitleEditable 
                         ? (object)new { @disabled = "disabled", @style = "width:250px;" } 
                         : (object)new { @style = "width:250px" })
</td>
```

Note that the id = "Title" is not necessary in the `HtmlAttributes`, the helper will create an Id for you.

**EDIT**
There is some confusion about the `Selected` property on the `SelectListItem`. This is **NOT** used when using a `DropDownListFor`, it in only used in a `DropDownList`. So for a `DropDownListFor` you set the propert of your model to the value you want selected (the `model.Title = 5;` mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

If `Model.TitleList` is a `SelectList`, you can specify the selected value when you populate the `SelectList` during your model creation. As an illustration:

```
var model = new MyViewModel();
var domainEntity = GetMyDomainEntity(id);

// Create a selectlist using all your titles and specifying the Title value of the item
// you're viewing as the selected item. See parameter options if you're not supplying
// an object as the selected item value
model.TitleList = new SelectList(GetAllTitles(), domainEntity.Title)
```

Then you'd simply do your `Html.DropDownListFor` in your view.

Comment: But in my controller the selectlist is getting filled as below:  model.TitleList = new SelectList(GetAllTitles(), "Code","Value"); In this case as I m using the other overloaded method, how to set the selectedValue property of this selectList?

Comment: You can populate it as `model.TitleList = new SelectList(GetAllTitles(), "Code", "Value", domainEntity.Title)`. Basically add that 4th parameter that is the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly what I like to do is having a static class such as this:

```
public static class SelectLists 
{
    public static IList<SelectListItem> Titles(int selected = -1) 
    {
        return GetAllTitles()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem  { 
                    Value = x.Id.ToString(), 
                    Text = x.Description, 
                    Selected = x.Id == selected
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

And then in my views:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, SelectLists.Titles(Model.Title), !Model.IsTitleEditable ? (object)new { id = "Title", @disabled = "disabled", @style = "width:250px;" } : (object)new { id = "Title", @style = "width:250px" });
```

All my SelectLists are in that class, if I had too much of them I would separate within different classes.

I find it useful because if you need the same dropdownlist in another view/action, you don't have to repeat the code in your controller.